# Android - Access to Mysql Database -communicationsexception

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.2-froyo

I have a problem with the application I'm developing.
I am trying to connect to a database in Mysql that is in local in a WIFI network with my application on android.
I use for this, a direct method, with mysql-connector-java 5.1.23.
The application works fine on my nexus one (Android 2.3). But not on my nexus 7 (Android 4.2).
I've got the error : `"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.communicationsexception communications link failure"`

However, using an application of the market (connect2sql) on my nexus 7, I can easily access the database.
I guess (but I don't understand) that the error is related to the version of Android (2.3 vs 4.2).
Is that someone already encoutered this problem ?

Thank you very much for any help on the subject.

(I use Eclipse to develop with JDK 1.6 - The target API is 17, corresponding to Android 4.2)

This is the code :

```
package fr.apln.Rocketry_Challenge;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.ResultSet;  
import java.sql.Statement; 
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class testdirectmysql extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_testphpmysql);

        try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/Rocketry_Challenge_1", "android", "XXXXX");  

        Statement st = con.createStatement();  
        st.executeQuery("USE Rocketry_Challenge_1;");
        Toast.makeText(this,  "C'est passé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM projets;");  
        while(rs.next()) {  
        Toast.makeText(this, "Projet : "+rs.getString(2)+" / Club : "+rs.getString(3), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }  
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Toast.makeText(this,  String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: I think it is not advisable to remote direct connection to a database server. Web service/api would be ideal for that.

Comment: Thanks hardcoded,since the database is on a local network (WIFI available), I do not have a security problem. A Webservice in php (for example) is heavier implement for low added value I guess ...

Comment: Thanks mohammed momn, I added the code...

Answer (score 0):

I saw another developer yesterday, I could solve my problem.
My function was in the main thread, so Android 4.2 blocked it because it was too slow...
This was not the case for Android 2.3.
I tried making my function in an Asynctask and it works correctly.

Thank you for your answers.